# How to convert 'SeriesGroupBy' object to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns that I am filtering in hopes of using the output to filter another dataframe further. Ultimately I'd like to convert the group by object to a list to further filter another dataframe but I am having a hard time converting the SeriesGroupBy object to a list of values. I am using:

```
id_list = df[df['date_diff'] == pd.Timedelta('0 days')].groupby('id')['id'].tolist()
```

I've tried to reset_index() and to_frame() and .values before to_list() with no luck.

error is:
'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute tolist

Expected output: Simply a list of id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
pd.Timedelta('0 days')].groupby('id')['id'].apply(list)
```

Also, I am a bit skeptical about how you are comparing `df['date_diff']` with the groupby output.

---

EDIT: This might be useful for your intended purpose (s might be output of your groupby):

```
s = pd.Series([['a','a','b'],['b','b','c','d'],['a','b','e']])

s.explode().unique().tolist()
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: curious about what you are skeptical about. Is it the Timedelta '0 days' portion?

Comment: no, the groupby operation will return a series with each value as a `list`. are you comparing 2 series with list elements with the `==` operator?

Comment: ah yes I see what you mean. I simply want a list of unique id's so that I can filter another dataframe similar to something like this...

final_df = df[df['id'].isin(id_list)]

Comment: yea so for that you will have to take the series of lists (output of the groupby) and then flatten it. I have added the code for that as well

Comment: I am still fairly junior to python so thank you for taking time out of your day to help me out. I still don't fully understand why the initial output was a series with each output as a list or if there was a better more efficient way to get the same final output. I'm just glad it works. Thanks again

Comment: let me share my blog with you. I have a very old article talking about how to master groupby and in general some aspects of pandas. Maybe that would help you get started. If you need any more guidance, feel free to connect with me on linkedin as well.

Comment: [this](http://akshaysehgal.com/groupby.html) is the blog from my website.

Comment: much appreciated. I will check it out.